# Polymer with ASP.NET Core, return "violation of Content Security Policy directive"

Tags: azure, polymer-1.0, content-security-policy

I have created a new Polymer app using the latest version, Polymer 1.7.1

It is a very simple layout doing almost nothing but if I run it either from my Windows 10 machine or from a public Azure Web Role, all browsers (Chrome, Android default and Edge) return this error:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following 
Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, 
a hash ('sha256-y9OeFTMzuy/UmFD54M4yHw1fwa70f6ptTlq7FUPrn+M='), 
or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. 
Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, 
so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"default-src 'self'". 
Note that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Now, I do understand the meaning of CSP but this is not the only Polymer Project that I have but it's the only one giving me this problem.
How can I mark it "safe" and remove these warnings from the browsers?

### Solution

At the end, it was ASP.NET Core which was not adding any header, by default, which was causing Polymer to throw the CSC exception.

Solved with this:

```
        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy",
                                     "default-src 'self' * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:");
            await next();
        });
```

Comment: Did you set the CSP? Can you modify it?

Comment: No, I didn't set anything actually related to CSP and yes I can modify the header but still doesn't work